# Error: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcBBs.png)When using navigation v5, I encounter an error can not read property navigate of undefined

const Categories=({navigation})=> {

```
return (
    <View >
       
        <Text style={Styles.TextCategories}>دسته بندی ها</Text>
        {/* ---------------------------------------------------------------لایه کلی صفحه---------------------------------- */}
        <View style={Styles.View}>
            {/* --------------------------------------------------------------- لایه دکمه ها---------------------------------- */}
            <Button style={Styles.Button} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Homesales')}>
                <MaterialIcons name="waves" size={30} color={"#0c7656"} />
                <Text style={Styles.Text}>زمین</Text>
               
            </Button>
```

```
const Home=()=>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((response)=>console.log(response.data)).catch((e)=>console.log(e))
  },[])
  return (
 <Categories/>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Home);
```

Comment: Can you show where you are using Categories?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). That error tells you that `Categories` is being called with no arguments (or with `undefined` as the first argument). We can't help you more than that without a much more complete excerpt of your code.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: `import React, { Component,useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../Components/SearchBar';
import Categories from '../Components/Categories';
import axios from 'axios';
import ApartmentSales from '../Pages/ApartmentSales';
const Home=()=>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((response)=>console.log(response.data)).catch((e)=>console.log(e))
  },[])
  return (
 <Categories/>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Home);
`

Comment: If you want to add some extra code it is better to edit your question instead of mashing everything into a comment

Comment: So what does the `Categories` module look like? Possibly you had to do `import {Categories} from '../Components/Categories'`... but you don't show enough code to know.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use navigation hook of react-navigation-v5?? instead of passing navigation as prop try to "useNavigation()" hook, this way you will have access to a valid navigation object from anywhere

const navigation=useNavigation()

for using navigation
navigation.navigate('')

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a object that does not has property 'navigation' to component Categories

You need to check at the parent component, seem that props/navigation is null here.